# Ember JS and ember-uploader saving file to S3 with unique name

Tags: amazon-web-services, ember.js, amazon-s3

I am using ember-uploader to upload files directly from my client to S3.

Currently I am generating a unique filename on the server when signing my S3 upload like this:

```
return Response(
    {"acl": "public-read",
    "awsaccesskeyid": "ACCESSKEY",
    "bucket": "bucket",
    "policy": policy_encoded,
    "signature": signature,
    "key": "uploads/%s.%s" % (unique_filename, file_name_extension),
    })
```

"key" contains my unique filename and that saves the file correctly onto S3 with the renamed filename.

If I were able to access the server's signed response using ember-uploader this wouldn't be a problem but it seems that the JSON response is all handled by the library itself - I could edit the library to achieve what I want but this doesn't seem to be the best solution.

The problem here is then getting that unique filename back to my client, how could I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems that you are able to access the returned payload, as seen [here](https://github.com/benefitcloud/ember-uploader#response).

```
var upload = uploader.upload(file);

upload.then(function(json) {
    // JSON should be the unmodified response from the server
});
```

Comment: If I do console.log at this point json is undefined upon upload. Could this maybe be a problem with ember uploader? How could I test this or figure out how I could get a response back from S3?